# Rounding a specific Hour in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I wonder how the following *SQL* code can be converted to *LINQ*.

```
declare @t table( hour datetime )

insert into @t select '19000101 14:38:12' union select '19000101 09:21:55'

select
  hour,
  case 
    when DATEPART( MINUTE, hour ) >= 30 
    then LEFT(convert(varchar, dateadd( HOUR, 1, hour ) , 108),2)+':00:00' 
    else LEFT(convert(varchar, hour , 108),2)+':00:00' 
  end 
from @t
```

My current query is:

```
List<RegistroVehiculo> listaRegistroVehiculoCompleta = 
  (from r in db.RegistroVehiculo
   where r.idPersona == oPersona.id
      && r.tipoRegistro == "S"
      && (
           (oHoraExtraGeneral.fechaDesde <= r.fechaRegistro && r.fechaRegistro <= oHoraExtraGeneral.fechaHasta) 
           ||
           (oHoraExtraGeneral.fechaDesde <= r.fechaEntrada && r.fechaEntrada <= oHoraExtraGeneral.fechaHasta)
         )
    orderby r.fechaRegistro
    select r).ToList<RegistroVehiculo>();
```

How I can make the list with rounded hours work?

Comment: Are you using Entity Frameowrk ?

Comment: yes codeNotFound I'm using EF!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Let clause inside your LINQ query?

Look, it would be something like this:

```
var xx = (from r in li
          let RoundHour = r.fechaRegistro.Minute >= 30 ?
                          TimeSpan.FromHours(r.fechaRegistro.Hour + 1) :
                          TimeSpan.FromHours(r.fechaRegistro.Hour)
          where r.tipoRegistro == "S" //whatever else goes here Just for the sake of brevity
          orderby r.fechaRegistro
          select new { rounded = RoundHour, 
                       registro = r}).ToList();
```

Please note that instead retrieving a list of RegistroVehiculo, we return an anonymous type, so, for every occurrence, you'll receive 2 things:

- the rounded hour
- the RegistroVehiculo object

I hope this approach helps you!

regards

Comment: wow excellent e! ... just 1 thing to change... we have to add the **value** in clausule to **r.fechaRegistro.Value.Hour**

Comment: ah indeed. I presumed it was only a datetime variable, but it is fine, I am happy it worked out for you :)